# PHP Function in ajax url?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm a new JQuery user and i have 2 questions

1. How can I use PHP function in url field, for example I'm using Codeigniter and I want to put base_url function as a url.
2. How can I request just an id from the page, not all the page.

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#module').change(function(){
        var module = $("select#module").val();
        var dataAll = 'module=' + module;
        $.ajax({
            url: "name.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : dataAll,
            dataType :"html",
            success : function(msg){
                $('#result').html(msg)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "and how can i request just an id from the page, not all the page" What does mean?

Comment: @A.Wolff - I think the idea is to somehow specify the id of a particular element that exists on the requested page and just retrieve or just use that element (and, presumably, its descendants). Like jQuery's `.load()` method can do.

Comment: @nnnnnn that makes sense! For OP, try: `$('#result').load('name.php #targetID');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a php variable into jQuery by echo-ing it. This is assuming that the page that provides this code is parsed as a php file.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/name.php",
        type : "POST",
```

For your second question. You cannot request part of a page. If you just want a part of the page, you'll need to parse it somehow, or write your own page that only provides the data you want to use.

Comment: That's assuming that js files are parsed as php files, or the script is included in a php file.

Comment: @Archer Fair point, but I am somewhat hoping OP knows that. Hossam: Code in comments is unreadable. If the code you provide is in any case relevant add it to the question and notify a user via a comment.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can assign the result of the base_url() function to js variable and then echo it eg.

in your view:    `< ?php echo  "var baseUrl={base_url()}"  ?>`

In your js script file: `$.ajax({
        url: baseUrl,`

2) in your controller method you can  set content type to application/json and return json with with data that you need.